# Could someone explain me this strange Python for loop?

Tags: python, pynput

I was occupied on a project and I found a code that was perfectly what I was searching for, but there are parts that I don't understand could some of you explain me it please? This is the code that I found:

```py
from pynput import keyboard
from pynput.keyboard import Controller

keypress = Controller()

COMBINATIONS = [
    {keyboard.KeyCode(char='a'), keyboard.KeyCode(char='z')},
]

current = set()

def execute():
    for loop in range(0, 10):
        keypress.press('w')
        keypress.release('w')

def on_press(key):
    if any([key in COMBO for COMBO in COMBINATIONS]): # THIS PART
        current.add(key)
        print(current)
        if any(all(k in current for k in COMBO) for COMBO in COMBINATIONS): #THIS PART
           execute()

def on_release(key):
    if any([key in COMBO for COMBO in COMBINATIONS]): #THIS PART
        current.remove(key)

    with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener:
        listener.join()
```

I commented the parts that I don't understand with `#THIS PART` commend Thanks for helping:)

Comment: Would you mind fixing your indentation?

Comment: You're looking for [list comprehensions](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question can be divided into two parts:

### 1. List Comprehension:

First, list comprehension: which is a way to write a `for` loop in just one line. So, instead of writing:

```
result = []
for COMBO in COMBINATIONS:
    result.append(key in COMBO)
```

You can write it in one line like so:

```
result = [key in COMBO for COMBO in COMBINATIONS]
```

As you can see, `result` is a list of boolean values... either `True` or `False`. Which brings the second part;

### 2. [any()](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_any.asp) function

The second part is the function `any()`. This function returns `True` if one of the given items in `True`. And `False` if non of the given items is `True`.

---

So, the answer to your question is that this part:

```
any([key in COMBO for COMBO in COMBINATIONS])
```

It checks if the `key` exists in any of `COMBO` of the given `COMBINATION`.

Hope this answers your question!

Comment: I knew how the for loop works also the append function but what happens with the results.append**(key in COMBO)** I don't understand this part? What does COMBO precisely?

Comment: `COMBO` is just an iterator over every item in `COMBINATION`. It works the same as `loop` in `for loop in range(0, 10)`. Running `for COMBO in COMBINATION: print(COMBO)` will show you what `COMBO` looks like

Comment: Thank you so much for your answers!

Comment: To what would you change the title of this explanation so that others could find it easily. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

I understood better when I tried to apply it in a easy code. Thanks for your great explanation:)

```
import os
Passwords = ["abcd", "efgh"]
inpt = input()


for List in Passwords:
    if (inpt in List) == True:
        print("Correct password! : True!")
        os.startfile('Chrome.exe')


if any([inpt in List for List in Passwords]):
    print("Correct password! : True!")
    os.startfile('Chrome.exe')
```